# Can I use a flat data source for DOCX file with grouping or subblocks?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm wanting to merge into a DOCX file.  I've got a flat list of groups and participants, like this (but with more data elements):

```
$my_data=array(
  array('group'=>'Monday','name'=>'John Smith'),
  array('group'=>'Monday','name'=>'Lea Bitto'),
  array('group'=>'Monday','name'=>'Frank Regardi'),
  array('group'=>'Tuesday','name'=>'Bob Forehead'),
  array('group'=>'Tuesday','name'=>'Sue Compton'),
  array('group'=>'Tuesday','name'=>'Fran Gerzi'),
)
```

I'd like to merge this into a template that would result in:

```
Group Info
Group Name

Table:
Table header row
Table data row(s) merging participants for this group
(end table)
(Page break)
Next group...
```

I tried experimenting with both subblocks and headergrp, but couldn't make this work.  Is it possible to do this?  And if so, how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parentgrp` is done for that.

here is an example for doing what you're asking:

**Template :**

```
Here a paragraph having the property « page break before »
[c;block=tbs:page;parentgrp=group]
Group: [c.group]
----------------------------
|            Name          |
----------------------------
|  [c.name;block=tbs:row]  |
----------------------------
```

**PHP script:**

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('c', $my_data);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was editing my template in Google Docs, which didn't seem to have a page break before option.  So I defined block begin/end, with a page break before the end.  That of course leaves an extra page break at the end of the merged document.  In your example with the page break before, would that result in a blank page at the start of the document?

Comment: @KenTanzer: MsWord does ignore the page break before of the very first paragraph of the document. Thus, the first page will not be a blank page.